# Limit of the sequence

Tags: limits

Let $b_n$ be the real root of the following equation

$$x^{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}\;,$$ $n\geq2$

prove:
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n=2$, and moreover, $b_n$ is increasing.

Comment: This isn't a question. :-S

Comment: @Ben: The implied question is obvious.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if you say so :-)

Comment: Some users will downvote this or even vote to close it, since you’ve not stated it as a question and have not given any indication of what you’ve tried. It would probably be a good idea to revise it to accommodate them at least a bit.

Comment: obviously, $1<b_n<2$, so if we prove that $b_n$ is increasing, then the limit exists.

Comment: $x^{n}-1=(x-1)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i=(x-1)x^n$,then $x-2+\frac{1}{x^n}=0$, so if the limit exists ,then it must be 2

Comment: You need to suppose the root is positive. For even $n$, there is at least one negative root.

Comment: thank you. but I think it's fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{n-1}-\dots-1$. There is at least one real root $b_n$ in $(1,2)$. $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}-(n-1)x^{n-2}-\dots$, so $f_n'(b_n)>0$, hence only one root.  $f_n(b_{n-1})=b_{n-1}^n-2b_{n-1}^{n-1}<0$, so $b_n>b_{n-1}$. Let the limit be $1<b\le 2$.

If $b<2$, then $f_n(b)<0$ for large $n$, so $b_n>b$, contradiction.

Comment: the only thing you should prove is $f_n(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: $f_n(x)=(x-2)(x^{n-1}+...+1)+1$ is increasing

Comment: @Tao $f_n$ is not increasing. $f_n'(1)<0$. What you need is only $f_x(x)>,<0$ for $x>,<b_n$. Answer is fixed.

Comment: I  give a simple proof of the increasing result....

Comment: but $f_n(x)=(x-2)(x^{n-1}+...+1)-1$ are increasing on R

Comment: @Tao NO. Note $x-2<0$ for $x<2$.

Comment: NO,I think that my method is right. $f_{n}$ is increasing on R let alone [1,2], you $f'_n(b_{n})$ just holds for $b_n$ not $b_{n-1}$

Comment: @Tao Consider $f_2=x^2-x-1$ decrease on $[-\infty, 1/2]$. I do not need $f_n'(b_{n-1})>0$, I only need $f_n(b_{n-1})<0$ to obtain $b_{n-1}<b_n$.